# Is there a way to give a command a time delay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to give a command, such as `/say` or `/tellraw` a time delay?

For example I want my command to say something after ten seconds, but I don't really want a bunch of repeaters everywhere. Is there a way to do this with command blocks or alternative methods?

Comment: I edited your question to make it slightly broader to make it more helpful for other people by "demoting" `/say` and `/tellraw` to examples. These commands don't have any special delay functionality, so the answers will apply to all commands anyway.

Comment: That said: Good first question, and welcome to the site. Be sure to check out the [tour] if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scoreboard values and dummy variables.

### Example

Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Timer dummy
```

Run every tick for each individual command:

```
/scoreboard players remove cmd1 Timer 1
/scoreboard players test cmd1 Timer 0 0
v comparator(before 1.9) or conditional (after 1.9) v
/your_command_here
```

Run to start delay:

```
/scoreboard players set cmd1 delay_in_20ths_of_a_second
```

As you can see, this is scalable for as many commands as you need.

Comment: I haven't downloaded the newest snapshot, but at least i will know how to do it when 1.9 comes around.

Comment: If you aren't using 1.9, you can use a comparator to regular command block in place of the condintional. That's why it says comparator or condititonal(1.9). Sorry if i was overly vague.

Comment: You should avoid using the `*` wildcard where possible. It's an expensive operation that should not be used on a clock, as it has to cycle through every single playerscore stored on the scoreboard (and not only those specified in the objective). As well, using it to modify a score rather than reset will bloat the scoreboard because now every single player tracked has a new score in "Timer". It should only be used for one-time situations, such as at the end of a minigame.

Comment: @Skylinerw Oh, didn't think about that. Edited the answer so it's less resource intensive. Thanks for the help!